# recaptcha working on local but not on live wordpress sites

Tags: forms, captcha

Hi I have a form I've made that works on my local machine but doesn't run the get_file_contents on the live server as it returns NULL on the response?

Form:

```
 <form name="contactUS" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mail/contact-us-mail-recaptcha.php" method="post">

<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
<input name="message" type="textarea" placeholder="Please describe your project and the work to be done?">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<site key>"></div>
<button type="submit" class="nsc-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Server Code:

```
<?php

$recaptcha_secret = '<secret key>';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$captchaResponse); 

$result = json_decode($response, true);

if($result == true){

//do success
}else {

    var_dump('ip:' . $ip);
    var_dump('captchaResponse:' . $captchaResponse);
    var_dump('response:' . $response);
    var_dump('result:' . $result);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Make sure you added your domain URL in google developer recaptcha configuration.

Comment: thank you yes the url is added I confirmed this other wise there is an error  recaptcha box on the form

Answer (score 0):

> Tip A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

So most probably `allow_url_fopen` is set to false on your server.

But you shouldn’t use that function - use [`wp_remote_get`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) instead.

Comment: I've done a phpinfo() and it shows allow_url_fopen is on so does file_get_contents not work at all with wordpress? why is it working locally? It's the same code locally and on server I'm just editing and copying straight across

Comment: `file_get_contents` is PHP function - WP can't change how PHP works. So it's not WP that changes its behavior. You have to check PHP config on both servers. BUT, as I've already stated, you should use `wp_remote_get` instead (using file_get_contents with URLs is rather bad practice and can cause security problems).

Comment: I will update it to wp_remote_get once its working thanks. I'll check the config is the same on both servers but as I already said the allow_url_fopen is on on the live server so should be working.